# How to setup and test a data source configuration class in a spring boot app with multiple data sources?

Tags: spring-boot, testing, spring-data-jpa

Having challenges trying to test a secondary data source config class. Recently added a second data source to an existing spring boot application. Generically speaking the project is structured like this... (please forgive the somewhat wonky structure this is a bit of a meatball project)

```
├───src
│   ├───main
│   │   ├───java
│   │   │   └───com
│   │   │       └───myApp
|   │   │          │       
|   │   │          ├───config
|   │   │          |   └───datasourceConfigurations
|   │   │          |       ├───LegacyDataSourceConfiguration.java
|   │   │          |       └───PrimaryDataSourceConfiguration.java
|   │   │          ├───controller
|   │   │          |    ├───primaryController
|   │   │          |    └───legacy
|   │   │          |        └───legacyController
|   │   │          ├───models
|   │   │          |    ├───legacy
|   │   │          |    │   └───legacyModels
|   │   │          |    └───primary
|   │   │          |        └───primaryModels
|   │   │          ├───repository
|   │   │          |    ├───legacy
|   │   │          |    │   ├───legacyCustomRepo
|   │   │          |    │   └───legacyRepo
|   │   │          |    └───primary
|   │   │          |        └───primaryRepo
|   │   │          └───service
|   │   │              │   └───legacy
|   │   │              │       └───legacyService
|   │   │              └───primaryService
|   |   └───resources
|   │       └───application.yml
│   └───test
│       ├───java
│       │   └───com
│       │       └───myApp
│       │           ├───config
│       │           │   └───datasourceConfigurations
│       │           │       ├───LegacyDataSourceConfigurationTest.java
│       │           │       └───PrimaryDataSourceConfigurationTest.java

<REST OF THE TEST GO ON...>
```

When I run my tests I think during the set up the primary data source properties are being loaded instead of the legacy ones which I am aiming for... Here is the error:

**Error Message**

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Field customQuery in com.myApp.service.legacy.legacyService required a bean named 'legacyPersistenceUnit' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
        - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)


Action:

Consider defining a bean named 'legacyPersistenceUnit' in your configuration.
```

**Trace**

```bash
[ERROR] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 10.872 s <<< FAILURE! - in com.myApp.config.datasourceConfigurations.LegacyDataSourceConfigurationTest
[ERROR] com.myApp.config.datasourceConfigurations.LegacyDataSourceConfigurationTest.testLegacyEntityManager  Time elapsed: 0 s  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'legacyController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'service'; nested exception is org.springframework.b
eans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'legacyService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'nativeExecutor'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationE
xception: Error creating bean with name 'legacyCustomRepo': Injection of persistence dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'legacyPersistenceUnit'
 available
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'legacyService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'nativeExecutor'; nested exception is org.springframe
work.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'legacyCustomRepo': Injection of persistence dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No be
an named 'legacyPersistenceUnit' available
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'legacyCustomRepo': Injection of persistence dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBean
DefinitionException: No bean named 'legacyPersistenceUnit' available
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'legacyPersistenceUnit' available
```

That `legacyPersistenceUnit` is defined in the legacy data source configuration class with the builder, here:

```java
        return builder
                .dataSource(dataSource)
                .packages(
                        CommonAppConstants.LegacyDataSourceConfigParams.LEGACY_ENTITY_BASE_PACKAGE,
                        CommonAppConstants.LegacyDataSourceConfigParams.LEGACY_REPOSITORY_BASE_PACKAGE
                )
                .persistenceUnit("legacyPersistenceUnit") // <-- RIGHT HERE, used to wire up the repo class to the correct data source
                .build();
```

I have a strong feeling the test is being configured with the primary data source properties, not the newly added legacy data source.
I confirmed the repo classes are correctly configured in a local dev env, so I know they can be accessed and work. Also I experienced a similar setup/config issue during development (adding the second data source) where the error would state something like,
"oh this bean doesn't exist" and as soon as I replaced the referenced entity with something from the primary data source instead of the added legacy source everything started working.

I am trying to understand/discover the most direct way to point a test configuration to a specific data source? Any Ideas? What I am doing wrong in the set up here?

Here are the relevant files:

**TEST CLASS**

```
package com.myApp.config.datasourceConfigurations;

import com.myApp.shared.CommonAppConstants;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.test.context.ActiveProfiles;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertNotNull;

@SpringBootTest
@EnableConfigurationProperties
class LegacyDataSourceConfigurationTest {

    @Autowired
    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "legacyPersistenceUnit")
    @Qualifier("legacyEntityManagerFactory")
    private EntityManager legacyEntityManager;

    @Test
    public void testLegacyEntityManager() {
        assertNotNull(legacyEntityManager);
    }

}
```

**DATA SOURCE CLASS (LEGACY)**

```
package com.myApp.config.datasourceConfigurations;

import com.myApp.shared.CommonAppConstants;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryBuilder;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Profile;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.sql.DataSource;

@Profile("test")
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        entityManagerFactoryRef = CommonAppConstants.LegacyDataSourceConfigParams.LEGACY_ENTITY_MANAGER_FACTORY,
        transactionManagerRef = CommonAppConstants.LegacyDataSourceConfigParams.LEGACY_TRANSACTION_MANAGER,
        basePackages = CommonAppConstants.LegacyDataSourceConfigParams.LEGACY_REPOSITORY_BASE_PACKAGE
)
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class LegacyDataSourceConfiguration {

    @Bean(name = CommonAppConstants.LegacyDataSourceConfigParams.LEGACY_ENTITY_MANAGER_FACTORY)
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean legacyEntityManagerFactory(final EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder,
                                                                             @Qualifier("legacyDataSource") final DataSource dataSource) {
        return builder
                .dataSource(dataSource)
                .packages(
                        CommonAppConstants.LegacyDataSourceConfigParams.LEGACY_ENTITY_BASE_PACKAGE,
                        CommonAppConstants.LegacyDataSourceConfigParams.LEGACY_REPOSITORY_BASE_PACKAGE
                )
                .persistenceUnit("legacyPersistenceUnit")
                .build();
    }

    @Bean(name = CommonAppConstants.LegacyDataSourceConfigParams.LEGACY_TRANSACTION_MANAGER)
    public PlatformTransactionManager legacyTransactionManager(
            @Qualifier(CommonAppConstants.LegacyDataSourceConfigParams.LEGACY_ENTITY_MANAGER_FACTORY) EntityManagerFactory legacyEntityManagerFactory) {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(legacyEntityManagerFactory);
    }

}
```

Any thoughts?